# Como fazer uma requisição e atualizar um estado antes do render

Tags: api, react, axios, render

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e estava a criar um PrivateRouter.

Como estou usando uma API Fake (hai-server) ele me gera um token no login e eu consigo bloquear as chamadas de algumas rotas se não passar esse token, não existe um verifyToken, então tive a ideia de validar o PrivateRouter através de uma chamada em uma dessas URLs e me dando sucesso eu alterava uma variável ou estado pra validar o componente como na imagem.

Só que, o React por ser assíncrono ele renderiza o return antes de retornar a chamada, tentei com useEffect e useEffect mas sem sucesso.

Alguém teria uma ideia, sei que existe outros métodos mas esse foi que imaginei para o tipo de APi que estou usando pra ter mais segurança depois que fazem Login..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente para evitar que a renderização seja feita antes do retorno de uma requisição eu uso if antes do return, retornando qualquer coisa que eu queira, por exemplo:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { retorno: false }

  async function req(){
     //requisicao feita aqui com retorno
     //.then seta retorno = true
  }
  render() {
    if(!this.state.retorno){
       //se o retorno for false ele retorna qualquer coisa que você queira
       return({/* qualquer coisa aqui */});
    }
    //se for true ele vai retornar o render normal
    return();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar renderização condicional...

```
export default class App extends Component {

     state = { requisicao: null }

     funcaoDeRequisicao = async () => {
          //aqui faz a requisicao e seta o estado
     }

     return requisicao && <Text>TESTE</Text>

}
```

O que vai ocorrer é que o texto após o operado '&&' só vai ser renderizado caso o estado 'requisicao' seja diferente de null, undefined ou false.